# Deriving step size/learning rate in the hinge loss passive-aggressive/perceptron algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, perceptron

Recall the perceptron algorithm:

*cycle through all points until convergence*

$\text{if }\, y^{(t)} \neq \theta^{T}x^{(t)} + \theta_0\,\{\\  
\quad \theta^{(k+1)} = \theta^{k} + y^{(t)}x^{(t)}\\  
\}$

Here's a new update equation with $\eta_k$ as the step-size (aka learning rate):

$\theta^{(k+1)} = \theta^{k} + \eta_k y^{(t)}x^{(t)}\\$

The algorithm, at every step, selects a $\theta$ that minimizes the quantity:

$\frac{\lambda}{2}||\theta-\theta_k||^2+Loss_h(y^{(t)}x^{(t)}\theta)$

where

$Loss(y^{(k)} \theta^{(k)} \cdot x^{(k)}) = max\{0, 1-y^{(k)} \theta^{(k)} \cdot x^{(k)}\}$

The closed form of the equation for the perceptron update is:

$\eta_k = \min\{\frac{1}{\lambda},\frac{  Loss (y^{(k)} \theta^{(k)} \cdot x^{(k)} ) }{\left \|  x^{(k)} \right \|^2}\}$

How is this derived? I can't find any on this topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Our objective is $min~ \frac{\lambda}{2}||\theta - \theta^k||^2 + max\{0, 1-y\theta x\}$

Let's distinguish 2 cases:

a) $max\{0, 1-y \theta x\} = 0:$ In this case, we minimise our objective by setting $\theta = \theta^k$, i.e. $\eta = 0$.

b) $max\{0, 1-y \theta x\} > 0:$ In this case, our objective function becomes $\frac{\lambda}{2} ||\eta y x||^2 + 1 - y(\theta^k + \eta y x)x$

Now calculate for which value of $\eta$ this function is minimised (by taking its derivative and setting it to 0).